# flask_pymongo : PyMongo vs MongoClient : [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-pymongo

I have a huge flask application and I use the `PyMongo` class from `flask_pymongo` for MongoDB operations. My issue is in development environment.

I have a `MONGO_URI` in my `config.py` like this:

```
MONGO_URI = "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster-name.pihvl.gcp.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

Usage in my app looks like this:

```
# This is how I have initialized it in '__init__.py'
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo(app)

# This is how I access collections in the specified DB
document = mongo.db[collection_name].find() # Throws the below error
```

This worked fine until a couple days ago when I reinstalled Windows and also Python from scratch.
Now the same code throws the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: cluster-name-shard-00-01.pihvl.gcp.mongodb.net:27017: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

But using `MongoClient` instead of `PyMongo` works just fine, like this:

```
# Using MongoClient and setting 'ssl_cer_reqs'
from flask_pymongo import MongoClient
import ssl
mongo = MongoClient(app.config['MONGO_URI'], ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

# This works just fine
document = mongo[db_name][collection_name].find()
```

**Questions**

What changed with `PyMongo` when I reinstalled everything? I don't want to use `MongoClient` simply for the fact that there are over 100 endpoints and it is a nightmare to shift now, and also I prefer `PyMongo` because I don't have to specify the `db_name` in every query, it gets that from the `MONGO_URI`.

What am I missing and how do I make it work with `PyMongo`? Is there a way to set the `ssl_cert_reqs` while using `PyMongo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: Do this only if you're facing this issue in development environment**

All I had to do was add `&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE` to my `MONGO_URI` in my `Development Configuration` so now my `uri` would change from:

`mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster-name.pihvl.gcp.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

to:

`mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster-name.pihvl.gcp.mongodb.net/db_name?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE`

Answer (score 0):

Something in the certificate chain will have changed. pymongo has specific documentation on how to troubleshoot this issue:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html#troubleshooting-tls-errors

Answer (score 0):

pip install certifi

```py
import pymongo
import certifi

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING, tlsCAFile=certifi.where())
...
```